# Usage of Scala Future in Playframework?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

When using Playframework, I am sometimes faced with this situation :

```
def myFunction:Future[String] = {
    // Do some stuff
}

myFunction.onComplete {
    case Success(myString) => // Du Stuff
    case Failure(error) => // Error handling
}
```

But as stated in the Scala doc, `Future.onComplete` returns a Unit. 
How can I use those in Playframework when `Action` functions for example expect a `SimpleResult`? What are the best practices for handling Futures?

EDIT : I should add, I am using Play-2.2.x branch which has traded the Play Future for the Scala Future.

Comment: Interesting link @flavian, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Async`:

```
def index = Action{
    val myFunction:Future[Option[String]] = //
    Async{
      myFunction.map{
        case Some(x) => Ok(x)
        case None => InternalServerError
      }
    }
}
```

Basically you tell play that: Whenever `myFunction` is evaluated, return the result back to User. The trick here is to `map` on the `Future` content instead of using a callback, this lets you operate on the result.

The wonderful part is that it is still asynchronous. In the sense that the http request thread evaluation index will not get blocked.

Some documentation on it [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaAsync).

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I know Async is a wrapper expecting a `Future[SimpleResult]` while `onComplete` returns a Unit. Making this not compiling. And I should have added I am using Play 2.2.0-M2 which has switched Play's Futures by the native Scala Futures.

Answer (score 2):

Play (at least in 2.1) adds an `extend1` method that you might find useful:

```
def myFunction: Future[String] = ???

myFunction.extend1 {
  case Redeemed(v) => s"Got result string: $v"
  case Thrown(t) => s"Got throwable: ${t.getMessage}"
} // : Future[String]
```

It's probably better, however, to have computations that fail explicitly, using e.g. `Option` (as Jatin demonstrates), `Either`, or `scalaz.\/`.

Edit: as you point out, `PlayPromise` is deprecated in Play 2.2. It's trivial to emulate its behaviour with the `Future` methods, for instance:

```
myFunction.map(v => s"Got result string: $v").recover {
  case t => s"Got throwable: ${t.getMessage}"
}
```

If you wanted to recreate the `extend1` syntax it would be simple to add the appropriate implicits.

Comment: Indeed, in versions prior to `2.2`, I used `.extend1` however the signature is incompatible with `scala.concurrent.Future`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include one of the ways of doing this. You could also, for example, create a new `Promise`, feed it in an `onComplete` block, and return its `Future`.